# Using int() after concatenation of digits returns an error

Tags: python, string, integer, concatenation

I'm using `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` to list all possible numbers with certain digits. They have to be strings to concatenate them, but when I turn them back to integers, it produces an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p35.py", line 16, in <module>
    print int(num)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

This is the code that I used.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
for i in range(6):
    for j in combinations_with_replacement(['1','3','7','9'],i):
        num =''.join(j)
        print int(num)
```

Note that the goal is not to print `num`. I just need to convert them to integers because I need to do some numerical operations on them. This is just what reproduces the error.

How can I join the numbers while still being able to convert them back to integers?

Comment: print `num` and `j` and try to figure out what's happening

Comment: The exception message can't possibly be clearer...

Comment: When I print just `num`, only numbers are there. Do I have to remove the empty string part of the string? That doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: I was under the impression that there existed empty strings between the digits, which is why the error popped up. I now realize the first iteration returns just an empty string, which is what created the error.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for i in range(1, 6):
```

If we start the `range` in `0` (the default starting value), we'll get an initial empty list as the result of `combinations_with_replacement`, which will lead to a `num` with value `''`, an invalid integer.

Answer (score 0):

For the first iteration in inner loop you are getting '', which an empty string. And int() cannot operate on empty string. So just check if you have some value of num like this:

```
import ast  
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement  
for i in range(3):  
    for j in combinations_with_replacement(['1','3','7','9'],i):  
        num =''.join(j)  
        if num:  
            print int(num)
```